# How to use azure AD access token to bypass microsoft online login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am using following code to acquire token after authorization azure AD user.

```
 string clientId = "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx";
 var tenant = "xxxxxxxx.com";
 var serviceUri = "https://xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyy-yyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyy";


 string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"; 

  AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);


  var credentials = new UserCredential("wwwwwwww@xxxxxxxx.com", "*********");
  var authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(serviceUri, clientId, credentials);
```

After acquiring the access token i want to redirect user to a url which has microsoft login. I need to bypass login using access token. how can i achieve this. Please advice me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for confirming your question. Do you want to use the access token to access another resource which needs user sign in or you just want to use access token to access the resource with that service uri ?

Comment: Yes. I need to use the access token to access another resource which needs user sign in

Comment: Hi @BonieZat , I think it's not possible to do this. Because the resource is dfferent, even you can use the token in the head of the request, you will recieve error with invalid resource. I don't recommend you take this way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am really reluctant to the reosruce owner password credentials flow. I really do not like it and you seem to use it.

But to explain what you need to implement, is the "on-behalf-of" flow. This is well described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of). This will only work, if the respective permissions (scope grants) are already granted when you try to get an access token using the on-behalf of flow.