# Bypass Azure AD SAML

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I got SAML setup on my AD and I have the private and certificate PEMs along with the certificate and metadata and I want to know if it's possible to bypass the login from API? I'm developing a Node.JS API which I want to make requests to the server behind the SAML login but I need to bypass it with what I got.

Maybe a way to generate a token from Azure's API (to use as bearer authorization) would work like how you do it with OAuth?

I'm not asking for any other solution (like whitelisting etc.), I just need it to be token / API based

Comment: can the sample help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api

Answer (score 0):

To bypass azure ad , you may chose for the On behalf flow.

- For  single-page apps (SPAs), here we pass an access token to a middle-tier confidential client to perform OBO flows instead.

[image]

> This will only work, if the respective permissions (scope grants) are
> already granted when you try to get an access token using the
> on-behalf of flow.
>
> Here API A authenticates to the Microsoft identity platform token
> issuance endpoint and requests a token to access API B.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token
with grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id=xxx
&client_secret=saxx1s
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

[image]

Here we need to expose  api and here I am giving user.read

[image]

And exposed api

[image]

The response has  access token , refresh token

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read",
  "expires_in": 3269,
  "ext_expires_in": 0,
  "access_token": "xx",
  "refresh_token": "xxxx"
}
```

[image]

Please check [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

**Reference** : [how-to-use-azure-ad-access-token-to-bypass-microsoft-online-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923203/how-to-use-azure-ad-access-token-to-bypass-microsoft-online-login)

Comment: good effort but i've asked for SAML not oauth

Comment: Have you got to check [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow.md#obtain-a-saml-token-by-using-an-obo-request-with-a-shared-secret). Or check this [example](https://community.f5.com/t5/codeshare/bypass-azure-login-page-by-adding-a-login-hint-in-the-saml/ta-p/288225)  where one can use ?login_hint